# How to upload a Service Package to a Blob in Azure

Tags: azure

I need to create a deployment using REST API.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460813

There I have to provide a Package URL which refers to the location of the service package in the Blob service. I'm not clear about this and what do I have to do there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling the **Create Deployment** operation you need to call the **Put Blob** operation to upload the service package to your storage account (in a container).

After uploading the package its url will be something like this:

> http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mypackage.cspkg

You will need to pass this url in PackageUrl in the body of the **Create Deployment** operation.